# Removing Newline in a textarea when reading file with php

Tags: php, html, textarea, newline

I need a form with a textarea which is saved to a text file. This form should load the text from the file when the page refreshes so the text can be changed. Almost everything works fine, but i get a newline in the textarea when I hit send and the page reloads. The Text is saved without a newline at the end. The problem is that everytime I save the file I get a new newline at the end when i forget to remove it. I already tried trimming the text before displaying it in the textarea but that doesn't solve the problem. It seems to me that this is a weird behavior of the textarea or I'm just missing something. Maybe you guys can help me.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
if($_POST['text']){
    $file = fopen("test.txt","w+");
    fwrite($file, $_POST['text']);
    fclose($file); 
}
?>

<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="POST">
<textarea name="text" COLS=60 ROWS=8 wrap=hard>
<?php
$lines = file('test.txt');
foreach($lines as $line) {
    echo $line;
}
?>
</textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="button">
</form>
```

PS: I love this community and solved many of my problems here. This is the first time I have to ask you myself. I'm very new to php so pls be gentle :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to remove the newline before the `</textarea>` because your browser takes this for a new line in your textarea tag.

Comment: like i said i already tried the trim function. i need the newlines to be preserved. Just the one that gets added at the end of the textarea shouldn't be there. Even if I use trim(readfile("test.txt")) the textarea shows the curser at a newline and not at the end of the text.

Comment: Okay, you can just trim the last line so. I updated my answer to fit your needs

Comment: tried that already but it doesn't work :( the php code seems to be correct but still there is a newline created at the end in the textarea.

Comment: You maybe have a trailing endline at the end of you file. try to `var_dump($lines);` to show what's going on.

Comment: `<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>/var/www/html/tmp/src_4c7d4e9479fa0a9ddb02f835d5ac3240:21:</small>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=1)</i>
  0 <font color='#888a85'>=></font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'TEST'</font> <i>(length=4)</i>
</pre>TEST` this is my var_dump and there are no trailing endlines.

Comment: ok now i just did a workaround. I trim the text before saving and not displaying. This works for me. Thank you very much. I really appreciate that you took your time to help me +1

Comment: My answer didn't help you ?

Comment: wow sometimes the answer is so simple. Thank you this was the real reason for my problem.

Comment: Glad to help you ;-)